# PLS regression analysis based on Likert scale

Tags: partial-least-squares

Can dependent variable for PLS be based on Likert scale?

As i understand, dependent variable needs to be continuous. I wish to multiply frequency (i.e. integer value 3) with rating coming from likert scale (for example 5) to get value of Y as 15. is this acceptable as a continuous variable? If not, appreciate any alternate approach to calculate Y's.

Thanks a lot for your support in advance.

Comment: What is frequency and what is your Likert scale measuring?

Comment: frequency is occurrence of an activity resulting in an integer like 1 / 2/ 3. Rather than likert 'Guttman scale' gives me better orderly scale. I multiply Guttman scale rating (i.e. 5) to "frequency of occurrence i.e. 3) in order to create my dependent variable for PLS. Does it sound acceptable as continous variable?

Comment: No, and it doesn't sound like one that is interpretable. Why should a frequency of 1 times a Guttman of 5 mean the same as a frequency of 5 times a Guttman of 1?

Comment: Appreciate if you can help me with the following. I have created categories High, medium and low and I need to transform them in ordinal numbers for further calculation. What is the best approach to keep in mind while selecting these numbers or deciding levels? How can one justify teh chosen numerical value?   I'm thinking of considering ordinal scale where one end represents minimum and the other end represents maximum value, so that any value between min and max can be selected. (do not remember the name of this scale which is used in medical especially). Appreciate your support.

Comment: This depends on the substance of the questions and is likely a complex question. You may need to hire a consultant.

Comment: Do you know any consultant for guidance pls?

Comment: No. It's going to be largely a substantive question requiring consultation between you and someone who is a quantitative expert.